# Bounty did not produce any results, I should be able to increase it

Tags: feature-request

I know I can raise another bounty but after this one ends but it makes no sense that half of my points will be awarded to a low quality answer that did nothing to help me, SA or the universe.

Before the end of a bounty you should be able to increase it in which case the timer should restart as well.

Comment: A bounty is *advertising*, not a guarantee you'll get a result. If the advertising did not attract a proper answer, consider editing your question to ensure better responses.

Comment: `it makes no sense that half of my points will be awarded to a low quality answer` If it is a low quality answer then it will not be awarded half the bounty. An answer of a score of 2 or more will not be considered a low-quality answer.

Answer (score 13):

> I don't really know Stripe API nor how API Gateway works

You have this a bit backwards, it is your *question* that didn't produce any results.  With the most obvious problem with it that it is a statement, not a question.  And a vague one at that, "don't really" doesn't convey any useful information.  Getting an SO user to invest his free time to write a tutorial for you is probably going to take a bit more than fifty imaginary internet points.

All you can do is increase the bounty to keep it visible, maybe you'll find one.  Obviously you'll greatly increase the odds by limiting the scope so he doesn't have to write a book.  At a minimum post what you've tried in the past week.